# Can I use BizTalk as Message Broker in a Microservices architrecture?

Tags: architecture, microservices, biztalk, messagebroker

Usually when we speak about **Microservices** **architecture** we find **message broker** like **RabbitMQ** or **Kafka**.

But, in my current environment they already have BizTalk. From my understanding of BizTalk should do the job. So my question is more from a Best Practices point of view. It's easy to find comparison for RabbitMQ and Kafka, there isn't much on BizTalk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some use of BizTalk in a previous job and RabbitMQ at my current. While it's possible to use BizTalk for that purpose, it's not typical (according to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/esb-toolkit/typical-use-cases)).

There's some value in reusing what you already have, but in my experience there's way less overhead using RabbitMQ. It's simply a message broker and doesn't not a dozen other things as well, like BizTalk. It brings a lot of possible issues and, as you've seen, limited information as support from a general search.

Unless you are interested in using the transformation/repair/etc options BizTalk provides, I wouldn't recommend it. As far as I know it's usually used to facilitate communication with legacy or external software. And even then, if you're using microservices, you could always make another one for that purpose.

Comment: Probably the biggest hurdle to using BizTalk in a microservice architecture would be having each one deploy-able independently of the others.  Even using deployment frameworks such as BTDF, don't make for quick discreet deployments.

Comment: A point I had almost forgotten about. Deploying BizTalk took by far the longest of all services, though I have no experience with BTDF and how much time it would have been able to save.

Comment: Feel free to add it to your answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, BizTalk Server is a perfectly fine Message Broker, but it's still move of an application platform with messaging.

But, I've never seen an environment with existing BizTalk where RMQ or any other 'message broker' was actually necessary for anything.

Now, if you looking at Azure for a Services based app, you would choose Service Bus.

Answer (score 0):

Biztalk will store each message in SQL db, this adds latecy and scaling issues. 2ndly each message need to be converted to XML to leverage Biztalk Orchestration capability.

On the contrary Kafka stores it in local file system which makes it super fast.

Unless you have to leverage an adaptor of biztalk that is talking to a legacy system, you don't want it there. If there is then use Kafka to throw needed message copies to biztalk server and still don't use it to replace Kafka for communication between microservices.

Hope this helps